# Boolean value for cart item disappears on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the product is added to cart, its stored in localStorage even if its refreshed, but, the inCart button resets is value.In short, When an item is added by clicking on cart button, inCart sets to true and inCart text is displayed disabling the button, but, when browser is refreshed inCart sets to false and cart button is displayed again. I have stored all information of cart in localStorage.See below code

Product.js
(Below is the code for inCart)

```
<button className="cart-btn" disabled={inCart?true:false}
        onClick={() => {value.addToCart(id)}}>
        {inCart ? (
            <p className="text-capitalize mb-0" disabled>
            {" "}
            In Cart</p>
        ) : (
            <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"/>
        )}
</button>
```

context.js

```
componentDidMount = () => { 
        this.setProducts();

        // myCart value is retrieved
        const cart = localStorage.getItem('myCart')
        this.setState({cart: JSON.parse(cart) ? JSON.parse(cart) : []}, this.addTotal)     
    }


addToCart = (id) => {
        let tempProducts = [...this.state.products];
        const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
        const product = tempProducts[index];
        // Here inCart is set to true which remains until 
        // browser is refreshed
        product.inCart = true;
        product.count = 1;
        const price = product.price;
        product.total = price;
        this.setState(() => {
            return { products: tempProducts, cart: [...this.state.cart,
            product] };
        },
        () => {
            this.addTotal();
            localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(this.state.cart))
        });
    }
```

localStorage 'myCart' value

```
0: {id: 1, title: "Google Pixel 3 XL", img: "/static/media/product-1.c7704d10.png", price: 799,…}
company: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQA"
count: 1
id: 1
img: "/static/media/product-1.c7704d10.png"
inCart: true
info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify."
price: 799
title: "Google Pixel 3 XL"
total: 799
```

As seen above in localStorage the boolean value for inCart is stored even if browser is refreshed. How to set the value in Product's button component, so that 'In Cart' remains until the product is in cart?

Comment: Where is inCart defined for in the button?

Comment: inCart is a boolean value

Comment: Is this React?  Because then, for it to “react”, inCart should be a prop or part of state and referenced with this.props.inCart or this.state.inCart.

Comment: Yes its react... Boolean value is set to true and the button disables when false its vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to “react”, inCart should be a prop or part of state and referenced with this.props.inCart or this.state.inCart.

Comment: OK unless its part of the state it would not be stored in localstorage... Right?

Comment: Local storage is separate, but you can update the state from it if it is not null or undefined in componentDidMount.

Comment: You can also write from state to local storage.